# Keycloak admin client always gives 401 Unauthorized exception

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I'm using the `quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:23.0.3` docker image for my application's SSO.
I run the container with the following docker compose config:

```
keycloak:
        container_name: keycloak
        image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:23.0.3
        restart: always
        ports:
        - 8080:8080
        environment:
            KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
            KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
            KC_DB_URL_HOST: postgres # all KC_DB variable is provided
            KC_DB_URL_DATABASE: keycloak
            KC_DB: postgres
            KC_DB_USER: keycloak
            KC_DB_PASSWORD: pw1234
        depends_on:
        - postgres
        networks:
        - backend
        command: start-dev
```

The container runs as expected and I can login to the admin console without issues. My goal would be to automate the realm and client creation upon deployment. At the moment for that purpose I use a java application where I added the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
    <artifactId>keycloak-admin-client</artifactId>
    <version>23.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

The code with which I want to achieve my goal:

```
Keycloak keycloak = KeycloakBuilder.builder()
                .serverUrl("http://localhost:8080/admin")
                .realm("master")
                .clientId("admin-cli")
                .grantType(OAuth2Constants.PASSWORD)
                .username("admin")
                .password("admin")
                .resteasyClient(new ResteasyClientBuilderImpl().connectionPoolSize(10).build())
                .build();
        
        RealmRepresentation realm = new RealmRepresentation();
        realm.setRealm("application");
        
        keycloak.realms().create(realm);
        
        ClientRepresentation client = new ClientRepresentation();
        client.setClientId("application1");
        client.setSecret("appPw1");
        client.setProtocol("openid-connect");
        
        keycloak.realm("application").clients().create(client);
```

The execution gives me two times the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" jakarta.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Caused by: jakarta.ws.rs.NotAuthorizedException: HTTP 401 Unauthorized
```

I tried to change the serverUrl to `http://localhost:8080/auth`, but the result was `HTTP 404 Not Found`.

While I debugged it I saw something strange, the `keycloak` variable's authToken field was `null`.
 Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: The server url should be "http://localhost:8080". "/auth" is removed since v17